# System occasionally freezes when starting a GNOME application

Tags: freeze, 22.10

Occasionally, when I click on an application icon such as Files or Text Editor, the system freezes. Neither the mouse nor the keyboard responds. Pressing Caps Lock doesn't change the LED on the keyboard. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F4 doesn't do anything, obviously because the keyboard has stopped working. The only way I can get response from my PC is by connecting to it via the network and using SSH.

When I connected via SSH and typed `journalctl`, I saw the following relevant details. Can anyone see from these what the cause of the problem is?

```
Jan 15 15:23:11 pluto dbus-daemon[2502]: [session uid=1000 pid=2502] Activating service name='org.gnome.TextEditor' requested by ':1.43' (uid=1000 pid=2834 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
Jan 15 15:23:11 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 00800000 [EMPTY_SUBC] ch 3 [001fc25000 gnome-text-edit[28869]] subc 7 mthd 0000 data 001f906e
Jan 15 15:23:11 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000000000 engine 00 [PGRAPH] client 05 [HUB/CTXCTL] reason 02 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT] on channel 3 [001fc25000 gnome-text-edit[28869]]
Jan 15 15:23:11 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo:000000:0003:[gnome-text-edit[28869]] rc scheduled
Jan 15 15:23:11 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo:000000: rc scheduled
Jan 15 15:23:11 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo:000000:0003:0003:[gnome-text-edit[28869]] errored - disabling channel
Jan 15 15:23:11 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[2595]: channel 3 killed!
Jan 15 15:23:15 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
Jan 15 15:23:19 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 26924 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/fifo/nv50.c:228 nv50_runl_wait+0xe4/0x100 [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: Modules linked in: xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer overlay vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi coretemp snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg uvcvideo snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_usb_audio kvm_intel videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_codec uvc snd_usbmidi_lib videobuf2_memops r8712u(C) snd_hda_core videobuf2_v4l2 snd_ump kvm videodev snd_hwdep nouveau cfg80211 snd_pcm videobuf2_common irqbypass mc mxm_wmi crct10dif_pclmul drm_ttm_helper joydev input_leds polyval_clmulni snd_seq_midi ttm polyval_generic snd_seq_midi_event drm_display_helper snd_rawmidi ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel snd_seq cec mei_pxp mei_hdcp rc_core crypto_simd at24 dell_smm_hwmon cryptd
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper snd_timer rapl intel_cstate dell_wmi dell_smbios snd mei_me dcdbas i2c_algo_bit soundcore ledtrig_audio sparse_keymap i2c_i801 dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof mei ie31200_edac lpc_ich i2c_smbus serio_raw mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul e1000e psmouse ahci libahci xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas video wmi
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: CPU: 5 PID: 26924 Comm: kworker/5:0 Tainted: G         C OE      6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. Precision T1650/0X9M3X, BIOS A28 06/28/2018
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: Workqueue: events nvkm_runl_work [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: RIP: 0010:nv50_runl_wait+0xe4/0x100 [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: Code: 8b 40 10 48 8b 78 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 75 03 48 8b 1f e8 2e 89 dd cf 48 89 da 48 c7 c7 ae c4 f2 c0 48 89 c6 e8 8c db 39 cf <0f> 0b b8 92 ff ff ff eb a9 e8 9e 79 3e d0 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb77a8b793d68 EFLAGS: 00010246
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff96150181daa0 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: RBP: ffffb77a8b793da0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff96150454b208
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff96150454b230 R15: ffff9615f11bca90
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff96180dd40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: CR2: 000023c80d099000 CR3: 0000000205e44001 CR4: 00000000001706e0
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: Call Trace:
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  <TASK>
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? nv50_runl_wait+0xe4/0x100 [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? handle_bug+0x51/0xa0
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? nv50_runl_wait+0xe4/0x100 [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? nv50_runl_wait+0xe4/0x100 [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  nvkm_runl_rc+0x21f/0x400 [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  nvkm_runl_work+0x27/0x40 [nouveau]
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  process_one_work+0x223/0x440
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3f0
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0xe/0x20
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  kthread+0xf2/0x120
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel:  </TASK>
Jan 15 15:23:21 pluto kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```